# There is how many types of case condition expression

Tags: swift

Here is the code

```
enum Foo {
    case koo(p: String)
    case joo
}

let f1 = Foo.koo(p: "1")

// Case 1
switch f1 {
case .koo(_):
    break
default:
    break
}


// Case 2
if case Foo.koo(_) = f1 {

}

// Case 3. Compile error: Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Foo' and '(String) -> Foo'
if f1 == Foo.koo {

}
```

### Question

The case 1 and case 2 is passed. But case 3 will cause an error. So in this condition, is there only case 1 and case 2 to tell which Foo type is? Is there an another way to do it?

Comment: In both the `switch` and the `if`, `Foo.koo(_)` can be replaced with `.foo`: `if case .koo = f1 {
    print("yes")
}`

Comment: You may wish to review [these search results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+compare+enum+associated).

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to keep your `==` operator, and not have a `if case` in your 3rd example, here is how to fix it.

---

I added the `Equatable` conformance

```swift
enum Foo: Equatable { *** }
```

Then I added `(p: "foo")` below

```swift
if f1 == Foo.koo(p: "1") {
   // This is true!
}
```